# Find all combinations of N length of every element of one list associated with every element of a second list, with conditions

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, python-itertools

I'm trying to write a splitting algorithm. I have a first list with 24 elements, [x for x in range(24)], and a second list with 3 elements, [a,b,c].

Every element in the second list can be represented as a "bucket".

The set of the combination of the three buckets, set([a] + [b] + [c]), need to be equal to the set of all the elements in the first list of 24 elements, set([x for x in range(24)]). Each element of the first list can only be in one bucket at a time.

What I need, is to find all combinations of the above problem, where every element in the first list is in a bucket. I tried to pass list(itertools.product(list_1, list_2)) into itertools.permutations with a specified length of 24, but even with my 48 cores processor and 128gb ram, it's taking forever, as I cannot specify that every element in the first list can only be associated with one element of the second list.

I'm pretty desperate here. Can someone help me?

Comment: Does the order of elements in buckets matter?

Comment: No, they can be in any order you want

Comment: There are around 282 billion such combinations.  This is going to be slow no matter what you do.  And as soon as you call `list` on it, it will use up may terabytes of data.

Comment: That said, I would suggest using `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` to generate vectors of 24 combinations of a, b, and c.  And then turn each vector into 3 sets.  Be sure to `yield` each as you find it to avoid having them all in memory at once.  (You cannot call `list` on it.  Trust me.)

Comment: What do you need to do with these 282,429,536,481 solutions ? Generating them is going to take a long while, no mater how you approach it.  Putting them in a list will simply not fit in memory and writing them to disk will also take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) in the following way:

```py
assigned_buckets = it.product([a, b, c], repeat=len(list_1))
```

This produces one bucket assignment per element of `list_1` and yields all such combinations.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting list is too large for memory and would always take a long time to produce.

If you're only looking to generate solutions and iterate through them (presumably not all  282,429,536,481 of them), you could create a generator function using itertools.product:

```
from itertools import product
def makeBuckets(buckets,values):
    for combo in product(range(len(buckets)),repeat=len(values)):
        yield { b:[v for iv,v in zip(combo,values) if iv==ib]
                  for ib,b in enumerate(buckets) }
        
buckets = makeBuckets("abc",list(range(24)))
for _ in range(10): print(next(buckets))

{'a': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], 'b': [], 'c': []}
{'a': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22], 'b': [23], 'c': []}
{'a': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22], 'b': [], 'c': [23]}
{'a': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23], 'b': [22], 'c': []}
{'a': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21], 'b': [22, 23], 'c': []}
{'a': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21], 'b': [22], 'c': [23]}
{'a': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23], 'b': [], 'c': [22]}
{'a': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21], 'b': [23], 'c': [22]}
{'a': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21], 'b': [], 'c': [22, 23]}
{'a': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23], 'b': [21], 'c': []}
```